# I have been using Jasmin SMS gateway for sending SMS with GSM 7 Characters but not all characters where received in hand set

Tags: jasmin-sms

I have been using Jasmin SMS gateway for sending SMS with GSM 7 Characters but not all characters where received in hand set.

I tried using coding 0,8 etc
I tried to sent the message - '@ £ $ ¥ è é ù ì ó ç LF Ø ø CR Å å Δ _ Φ Γ Λ Ω Π Ψ Σ Θ Ξ ESC ƒ æ Æ ô ö ò û ù ÿ Ö Ü é ß Ü ä'

[I recieved only some characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjxGM.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the PDU encoded content? Etc. What do you mean by encoding 0,8?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.